# Wrong order in java.util.PriorityQueue and specific Comparator

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator

i am very confused with this little example of java.util.PriorityQueue and my own Comparator:

In this code i get a wrong order in the queue.
The result is: `5,8,7`instead of `5,7,8`
Is there anything wrong with my `Comparator<Vertex>` ? Thank you for your help.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PriorityQueue<Vertex> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>(new Comparator() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            Vertex u = (Vertex) o1;
            Vertex v = (Vertex) o2;
            return Integer.compare(new Integer(u.distance), new Integer(v.distance));
        }
    });

    Vertex vertex1 = new Vertex(1);
    Vertex vertex2 = new Vertex(2);
    Vertex vertex3 = new Vertex(3);
    Vertex vertex4 = new Vertex(4);

    vertex1.distance = 8;
    vertex2.distance = 5;
    vertex3.distance = 7;


    priorityQueue.add(vertex1);
    priorityQueue.add(vertex2);
    priorityQueue.add(vertex3);

}

private static class Vertex {
    int distance;
    int id;

    public Vertex(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `new Integer(…)`? Using the constructor of `Integer` instead of `Integer.valueOf` is discouraged, but even calling `Integer.valueOf` is unnecessary as Java’s auto-boxing will do it for you where required. But here it isn’t required at all as `Integer.compare` expects `int` values as arguments. So you are creating obsolete `Integer` objects and let Java’s auto(un)boxing convert them back to `int` values…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `PriorityQueue` doesn't store its elements in order. It gives them back to you in order.

If you called `poll()` three times on the `PriorityQueue`, you'd get your elements back in the appropriate order.