# PriorityQueue is not arranging duplicate elements in order [Duplicate elements descending order]

Tags: java, sorting, priority-queue

I have used priority queue to store elements in ascending and descending order but when there are duplicate elements it does not store in identical order.

**Ascending Order**

```
import java.util.*;
class PriorityQueueDemo {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pQueue
        = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();

    // Adding items to the pQueue using add()
    pQueue.add(2);
    pQueue.add(7);
    pQueue.add(4);
    pQueue.add(1);
    pQueue.add(8);
    pQueue.add(1);

    // Printing the top element of PriorityQueue
    System.out.println(pQueue);
    }
 }
```

**Output:-**

```
[1, 2, 1, 7, 8, 4]
```

Also if I am doing descending order it gives wrong output on all 3 cases :- lamda expression, comparator.reverseOrder and custom comparator....

**Descending Order**

```
import java.util.*;
class PriorityQueueDemo {
  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        PriorityQueue<Integer> pQueue
            = new PriorityQueue<Integer>((a, b) -> b - a);

        // Adding items to the pQueue using add()
        pQueue.add(2);
        pQueue.add(7);
        pQueue.add(4);
        pQueue.add(1);
        pQueue.add(8);
        pQueue.add(1);

        // Printing the top element of PriorityQueue
        System.out.println(pQueue);
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

```
[8, 7, 4, 1, 2, 1]
```

I want elements should be sorted.
Please help me!!
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrong order in java.util.PriorityQueue and specific Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784670/wrong-order-in-java-util-priorityqueue-and-specific-comparator)

Answer (score 2):

The output you are seeing is how the data structure is stored. Priority Queues in Java are implemented using heaps to determine the next element with priority.

You can see a visualisation using this [website](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/Heap.html) to help you understand why outputting the queue prints the way it does.

You can just remove elements to retrieve the next priority using `poll()`